# Project Euler #2; Code Fails to Output Correct Answer

Tags: java

Question Given: Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Could somebody help me out with figuring out the logic error with my code, it does not report the correct answer even though I think its right. Thanks! The output is 500693 when it should be 19544084.

```
long val1 = 1, val2 = 1, valEven = 2, total = 0;
while (val2 < 4000000 && val1<4000000) {
  total += valEven; //only add even numbers to total
  val1 += val2 + valEven;
  val2 += val1 + valEven;
  valEven += val1 + val2;
}

System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: That’s not enough to diagnose your problem. You must provide expected (correct) answer and the actual answer you get. Please edit your question and add those.

Comment: You should add more description to the problem. Just paste the problem statement for Euler Problem 2.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem Statement is (from [here](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=002)):

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

What you should do:

- List Fibonacci numbers less than 4 million
- Traverse over them and calculate sum of even numbers from that list

What you are doing wrong:

- Your logic of getting Fibonacci numbers is wrong
- You are not checking for even numbers

If you want to use the fact that "every third number in fibonacci is even" then you should get 3 numbers in sequence and then add third to your total. I think you are using the operator `+=` wrong.

```
a += b;
```

means

```
a = a + b;
```

This is how the code should be:

```
    long val1 = 1, val2 = 1, valEven = 2, total = 0;
    while (val2 < 4000000 && val1 < 4000000) {
        total += valEven; // only add even numbers to total
        val1 = val2 + valEven;
        val2 = val1 + valEven;
        valEven = val1 + val2;
    }

    System.out.println(total);
```

The answer is: `4613732`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. In the fibonacci sequence, there is one even number for every three terms. Would you mind describing how my logic of getting Fibonacci numbers is wrong and checking for even numbers?

Comment: @tsalemy If you want to use the fact that "every third number in fibonacci is even" then you should get 3 numbers in sequence and then add third to your total. I think you are using the operator += wrong. See update in the answer

Comment: yes makes a lot of sense, that was the key logical error I was not understanding. Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalized answer about debugging.

I added a println statement to your code to see the intermediate results.

Here's the runnable code.

```
public class FibonacciTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long val1 = 1, val2 = 1, valEven = 2, total = 0;
        while (val2 < 4000000 && val1 < 4000000) {
            total += valEven; // only add even numbers to total
            val1 += val2 + valEven;
            val2 += val1 + valEven;
            valEven += val1 + val2;
            if (val1 < 1000L)
                System.out.println(val1 + " " + val2 + " " + valEven);
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }

}
```

And here are the results.

```
4 7 13
24 44 81
149 274 504
927 1705 3136
5600910
```

As you can see, you're not calculating the Fibonacci sequence properly, so you're not calculating the sum of the even numbers properly.

First, let's fix the Fibonacci sequence.  You need 3 values to calculate the Fibonacci sequence correctly.  Let's also append an "L" to the long constants.

```
public class FibonacciTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long val1 = 1, val2 = 2, val3 = 2, total = 0;
        while (val1 < 4_000_000L) {
            if (val1 < 1000L) {
                System.out.println(val1 + " " + val2 + " " + val3);
            }

            val3 = val1 + val2;
            val1 = val2;
            val2 = val3;
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }

}
```

and here are the first few results.

```
1 2 2
2 3 3
3 5 5
5 8 8
8 13 13
13 21 21
21 34 34
34 55 55
55 89 89
89 144 144
```

Now that we're generating the Fibonacci sequence correctly, let's add up the even values.

```
public class FibonacciTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long val1 = 1L, val2 = 2L, val3 = 2L, total = 0L;
        while (val1 < 4_000_000L) {
            val3 = val1 + val2;
            val1 = val2;
            val2 = val3;

            if (val1 % 2L == 0L) {
                System.out.println(val1);
                total += val1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }

}
```

and here are the results.

```
2
8
34
144
610
2584
10946
46368
196418
832040
3524578
4613732
```

I get 4613732 for the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the clever fact that in the fibonacci sequence the numbers are odd-odd-even, odd-odd-even, ... (because of tha additions)

```
int valOdd1 = 1, valOdd2 = 1, valEven = 2;
long total = 0;
while (valEven <= 4000000) {
    total += valEven; //only add even numbers to total
    valOdd1 = valOdd2 + valEven;
    valOdd2 = valEven + valOdd1;
    valEven = valOdd1 + valOdd2;
}
```

And written out:

```
    valOdd1' = valOdd2 + valEven;
    valOdd2' = valEven + valOdd1';
    valEven' = valOdd1' + valOdd2';

    valOdd2' = 2*valEven + valOdd2;
    valEven' = 3*valEven + 2*valOdd2;

int valOdd2 = 1, valEven = 2;
long total = 0;
while (valEven <= 4000000) {
    total += valEven; //only add even numbers to total
    int nextValOdd2 = 2*valEven + valOdd2;
    valEven = 3*valEven + 2*valOdd2;
    valOdd2 = nextValOdd2;
}
```

The error was in the condition, (1) "not exceed" implies `<=` and (2) `valEven` must be tested as **the last result** at every loop step.
Also (3) the `+=` should simply be `=`. The much smaller wrong result was an effect of stepping with much larger steps through a sequence.